# Running isdigit() on a scanfed Character in C

Tags: c, validation, scanf

I am refreshing my C skills and am having a little bit of difficulty with a simple program I am working on. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // for isdigit()
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi()

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // first read in # of file events to follow, if not an int,
    // complain & abort
    char *input;
    input = malloc(2); // input[0] holds the character
                       // input[1] holds the terminator

    int numLines = 0;
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (isdigit((int)input)) {
        numLines = atoi(input);
    } else {
        printf("First line of input must be int type! Aborting...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //...
}
```

The problem is, then even when I enter a number (i.e. 2) it still outputs the aborting message and exits:

```
2
First line of input must be int type! Aborting...
```

I am having a hard time figuring out why it behaves like it is and what I should do to fix the problem. Shouldn't the '%c' specifier tell the compiler to take in the input as an ANSI character and then isdigit() should properly interpret that to be an integer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%c", &input);
if (isdigit((int)input)) {
```

to this:

```
scanf("%c", input);
if (isdigit(input[0])) {
```

As it is right now, you are overwriting the pointer itself, rather writing to the allocated memory.

Also, you need to null-terminate:

```
input[1] = '\0';
```

---

Furthermore, it's not necessary to allocate memory for this. You can get away with just:

```
char input[] = " ";
scanf("%c", input);
if (isdigit(input[0])) {
    numLines = atoi(input);
```

or alternatively:

```
char input;
scanf("%c", &input);
if (isdigit(input)) {
    numLines = input - '0';
```

Comment: But you can't use `atol()` on the single `char input;`, can you?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for suggesting an alternate way of doing it. I ended up using that as it's more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
char input[2] = {0};  // <<-- you don't clear the memory after malloc,
                      // your atoi might fail. No need for malloc here.
int numLines = 0;
scanf("%c", &input[0]);
if (isdigit((int)input[0])) {
    numLines = atoi(input);
} else {
    printf("First line of input must be int type! Aborting...\n");
    return 1;
}
```

And you're good. No need to dynamically allocate here, its just a waste of effort.

Comment: What are you talking about? He's giving an address of a `char *`, which is wrong but not for the reason he said, and while using `malloc` is unnecessary, it isn't wrong.

Comment: Note that nothing has set `input[1] = '\0';` yet, so `atol()` is unreliable.

Comment: You can't have an array of size 0.

Comment: @Dan - doesn't matter, really. the point is that he's passing a wrong pointer

Answer (score -2):

When you pass `&input` to `scanf`, you are passing a pointer to a `char *`. You should just pass the pointer itself, that is,

```
scanf("%c", input);
```